# HSQLDB + EclipseLink + generate DDL + DATE JODA TIME = wrong TIMESTAMP

Tags: spring, eclipselink, jodatime, hsqldb, jpa-2.1

I'm using:

```
Eclipselink 2.5.0
HSQLDB 2.3
JPA 2.1
Spring 4.0.5
```

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    ...

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Convert(converter = MyLocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDate date;

}
```

When the HSQLDB/Eclipselink generate the DDL, it generates the dabase field as:

```
TIMESTAMP
```

When I access (via select) this entity, my converter get a `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.sql.Date` and converts the value to a `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate`.

How can I force to generate the field as:

```
DATE // respecting the Temporal definition
```

Comment: I found a workaround, by definition the @Column(columnDefinition = "DATE"), but I need to fix this without using SQL.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting a `java.sql.TimeStamp` is very easy, you have not only `year`, `month` and `day` in the DB, but also `hour`, `minute` and `second` perhaps.

The only difference between `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` is `Timestamp` carries more information like `hour`,..

..., which means, it is correct for you to get a `java.sql.Timestamp`.

PS: `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` are both wrapper of `java.util.Date`..

Comment: I known the difference between Timestamp and Date, the fact is that I want/need to use Date type (year, month, day only) in database, and I need to generate the DDL with DATE and not TIMESTAMP.